# Select all ID's or Class's with getElementBy

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, getelementsbyclassname

I have a script that I'm running and I want to it to select all the ID's or Class's instead of just the first one.

```
<script type = "text/Javascript" >
    function color(){
        var d=document.getElementsByClassName("black")[0];
        d.setAttribute("style", "background-color:#333;");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code picks out the first element (with [0]) so it is not surprising that you only get that one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `[0]` in `document.getElementsByClassName("black")[0]` means that you're actually *discarding* all but the first, after selecting them. Use a loop if you want to iterate over the value returned by `gEBCN`.
2. Use `document.getElementsByTagName('*')` if you want *all* elements.

---

```
function color() {
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i=0; i<allElements.length; i++) {
        allElements[i].setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#333;');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the elements with a certain ID, you can rely on `querySelectorAll`, as in

```
var d = document.querySelectorAll("#temp");
```

Keep in mind some things:

1. It's semantically wrong, even if not syntactically, to have multiple elements with the same id.
2. `querySelectorAll` return a `NodeList` object, not a live collection. This means that if you add another element with id "temp", that won't be in the collection you got and you have to call querySelectorAll again.
3. `querySelectorAll` isn't supported by IE7 and previous versions.

You already have an answer for `getElementsByClassName`.